# Sql server top query

Tags: sql

I am experiencing some strange behaviour and I really don't have test date/ environments, so
Will this query return top 5 rows ordered by count, or will it take top 5 rows and sort them then. What would be the query for the first?

```
  select top 5 l.userId, count(*) "count" from Log l
  where ...
  group by l.userId
  order by "count" desc
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It couldn't possibly have taken more than a few minutes to create some test data, but yes, that query does what you want it to do. `TOP` does its job after `ORDER`.

Comment: Maybe not the test *data* but the *environment* (i.e. SQL Server) is the problem? Just a thought...

Comment: @scherand: The Express Edition is free. And even though it takes a while to install, it's something you'll want to have around for testing in any case, if you don't happen to have another database to play around with.

Comment: well, actually environments were not the problem, but the fact that i got strangely different results on two environments. and one was customer's test environment on which i couldn't create more data. Thanks for help, much appreciated

Comment: @sherand not having an environment is not an excuse if http://sqlfiddle.com/ exists

Answer (score 3):

It will return top 5 rows after group by and order by.

More on this

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189463.aspx

It will return top 5 results from the query you have without using top.

Answer (score 3):

This will execute whatever query you define, then return the first five rows of that query.